# Get Directions Google maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

There is a Google map and on it marked objects. With GPS defining man's place on the map.
The aim is to set the phone automatically detects and plot a route to the nearest object. How can it be obtained?

Comment: @user678396: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this tutorial very helpful:
http://www.anddev.org/google_driving_directions_-_mapview_overlayed-t826.html